# Freeze or make Stable Web-view When I Select Action Bar Back?Prevent Loading/reloading every time

Tags: android, webview, reload

I want to Prevent Page reload or Freeze the Current Web-view When I Select any menu from option menu

This is My Webview

```
    public class MyWebV extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mwview);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tb1);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web5);
        WebSettings set = webView.getSettings();
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        set.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        set.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        set.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        set.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        set.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        set.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        set.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        final ProgressDialog progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(MyWebV.this, "Please Wait", "Loading...");
        webView.requestFocusFromTouch();
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {

           public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressBar == null) {

                    progressBar.setTitle("Please Wait !");
                    progressBar.setMessage("Loading...");
                    progressBar.show();
                }
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                try{
                    if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                        progressBar.dismiss();
                    }
                }catch(Exception exception){
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {


        String url = "www.example.com/login.php";
        webView.loadUrl(url);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        webView.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.m_MyWebV, menu);


        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.about1) {
            Intent aboutIntent = new Intent(this, About.class);
            startActivity(aboutIntent);
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.set1) {
            Intent webIntent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(webIntent);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

}
```

I My Web-view I have Some Menus So When I click on any menu like Setting or About... It is showing  But After that When I go back to Home with Option or Back arrow from Action Bar or Option Menu Its Reloading

So I need to login and And check the previous page its difficult for every time.. Can any one suggest me how to freeze web-view or How to prevent reload with the same app menus...

**Update**

This is my about Us class

```
public class About extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.aboutus);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tb3);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.m_about, menu);

     /*something*/
     return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.home) {
        Intent mypIntent = new Intent(this, MyWebV.class);
        About.this.finish();
        startActivity(mypIntent);
        return true;
    }
    else if (id == R.id.about1) {
        Intent aboutIntent = new Intent(this, About.class);
        About.this.finish();
        startActivity(aboutIntent);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

so for example if this is action bar back [image]

so When I click on arrow Its reloading the webview.. On device Hardware back I have disabled... on hardware back its fine but... On action bar back its Reloading

Comment: Try this: webview.canGoBack() if it is true then put this code webview.goBack() else finish.
In your case you directly finish your app when canGoBack return true.

Comment: Can you answer.. Please I am not getting...

Comment: What i understand your question is you click on some menu and choose the option so your webview page is load that is ok. Now the problem is that when you click back button you want to exit from that screen but you can't right.

Comment: noo... Actually... Web is working fine... But When I select About us and setting page they are also working fine But When I select Action Back button... not Device.. Back-button .. Its going to web-view page but what ever the data in the web-view page is reloading... I need to proceed from Login again.. Is there any way to stop reload... and check the about us and setting menus then come back to same webstate.... without reload...    Note: My hardware back button lead to exit with alert... So I have added Action Backbutton in action bar...

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can achieve this thing by using startActivityForResult instead of normal startActivity

Comment: Another way to achieve this once you logged in successfully store that url in pref file and whenever you come to that activity load successful logged in page from pref file.To store url you can use webviewclient method "shouldOverrideUrlLoading".

Comment: Please make or Update your answer...

Answer (score 2):

I have just performed a test using two activities, a MainActivity containing a webView just like yours, and a menu button that opens a second activity (About.java), using the exact same intent that you used in onOptionsItemSelected().

After opening About activity from the menu, if I press my phone's hardware back button, it returns to MainActivity without reloading the contents of the WebView, so **it works as you expect**.

I think **the problem you are experiencing is with the code you use to go back to the main activity**. You may be using an Intent to open your main activity again from your secondary activities, causing a new instance of your main activity to be created, triggering onCreate(), and thus re-creating your WebView and reloading the page.

To test if that's the case, you can add some debugging statements inside onCreate() using **Log.d()** or **System.out.println()**, to check if it's being called when you try to return to your main activity (MyWebV). If you see your debug messages in the logs, it's because **you are not returning to your Main Activity properly**.

The way you should close your secondary activities to return to your main activity is calling:

```
finish()
```

That method will close current activity and restore the previous activity in the stack (your MyWebV activity in this case), without re-creating it, just calling onStart() and onResume(), which wouldn't re-create your WebView or reload the page.

Comment: I have added this finish(); on about But when I press on Action bar back button It reloading webpage.. On hardware back its ok... But I need Action bar back button to prevent Webview Reload... Most of users go for action bar back button

Comment: In your updated question, you are creating  an Intent to launch MyWebV, when user clicks in "R.id.home", there you would be creating a new instance of MyWebV. Using only finish() would go to previously opened activity. I would also recommend making your secondary activities have just the back button in the ActionBar, to return to MainActivity, without allowing opening other activities. So user would just visit to one activity and return to main activity, and app navigation and structure is easier to understand.

Comment: If you prefer to keep menus in About and Settings, you can check Intent flags like FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP and many others that change the behavior of the intent to reuse an open activity, or bring it to front, and see which flags you need to get the right behavior.

Comment: Also, have you added debugging statements to onCreate() if you did, you can check "if" or "when" the webview is being re-created.

Answer (score 0):

About us or Setting page code where you used your custom back event or hardware back event.I think you are creating activity again inside your back event  which is doesn't require you just need to call finish method your Settings or About us page finish there and Webview page remain same as it is.Thats why i am requesting you post your code of one of page at least i can understand what you did exactly.

```
 public class About extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.aboutus);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tb3);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.m_about, menu);

         /*something*/
         return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.home) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.about1) {
            Intent aboutIntent = new Intent(this, About.class);
            About.this.finish();
            startActivity(aboutIntent);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    }

@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{ int id = item.getItemId(); 
   if (id == android.R.id.home) { 
                                  finish(); 
                                 return true; 
            } 
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
  }
```

Comment: I have added this finish(); on about But when I press on Action bar back button It reloading webpage.. On hardware back its ok... But I need Action bar back button to prevent Webview Reload... Most of users go for action bar back button

Comment: can you please post your code AboutUs.java or Setteing.java

Comment: Its fine at here `if (id == R.id.home) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }` but its not  working on action bar back